# PDF not scrolling using embed tag in IOS Device

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've used embed tag but PDF not scrolling in IOS device. can you please help me for the issue.

Comment: Please also show us your code, so we can help you with debugging.

Comment: I'm using this code
<embed src="PDF URL" width="500" height="375">